# Estimates sub-pixel shift directly in phase region

Tags: image-processing, matlab, estimation, image-registration

I try to estimates shift estimation directly in phase region, by following the proposed method in this *Sub-pixel Shift Estimation of Image based on
the Least Squares Approximation in Phase Region* by Fujimoto, Fujisawa and Ikehara (*Proceedings of 26th European Signal Processing Conference, EUSIPCO '16*, pp. 91–95. IEEE, 2016 [PDF](https://mega.nz/#!vp9WFDbb!pEG8pem9n2SaX8IHxbUxnD4JT6ngp0nF608T3zAeiJY)). Here is the flow chart described in the paper

[image]

If you're still with me, my issue raised when the author try to proceed with the subtraction of the integer shift with the phase difference $θ(k1,k2)$ (Equation (14) to smooth the phase difference. The authors however did mention that they obtained the slope $(a′,b′)$ of the integer shift using conventional phase-only correlation(POC) (Section III, paragraph above Equation (14)).

How can this step can be done? Since the phase difference is of a $60\times60$ matrix (assume the image dimension is so), while the integer shift consists only TWO values. How exactly were the slopes obtained?

Full matlab code I implemented:

```
function [ output_args ] = phasecorrlsa( refIm, shifIm )

F=(fft2(double(refIm)));
G=(fft2(double(shifIm)));
[m, n]=size(refIm);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
R=(F.*conj(G))./abs(F.*conj(G));
r=(ifft2(R));
[ap, bp, rhat]=lsa(angle(r));   %this is my slope a' and b'
[~,w] = max(r(:));
[del_hat2p, del_hat1p] = ind2sub(size(r),w);
del_hat2p=del_hat2p-1;
del_hat1p=del_hat1p-1;
theta=angle(F)-angle(G);
R=exp(1j*theta); %E6
theta=atan2(imag(R),real(R)); %E9
[a, b, thetahat]=lsa(theta);
del_hat1_ts=(m/(2*pi))*a
del_hat2_ts=(n/(2*pi))*b
thetapp=theta-rhat;   %equation 14, I guess something amiss here
%figure;
%surf(theta);
%figure;
%surf(thetapp);
[app, bpp, thetapphat]=lsa(thetapp);
del_hat1=(m/(2*pi))*app+del_hat1p;
del_hat2=(n/(2*pi))*bpp+del_hat2p;
if del_hat1>n/2, del_hat1=del_hat1p-m; end
if del_hat2>m/2, del_hat2=del_hat1p-n; end
output_args=struct('a',del_hat1, 'b', del_hat2);

end

function [ a, b, hat ] = lsa( theta )

[m, n]=size(theta);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
B=regress(theta(:), X);
a=B(1);
b=B(2);
hat=reshape(X*B,m,n);

end
```

Please lighten me on this issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cross-posted to [CS Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71595/9550).

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to comment on your Matlab code, but eq. (14) seems straightforward to me.  You have a phase difference field $\theta$ which depends on the two spatial wavenumber components $k_1$ and $k_2$, and which formes a wrapped plane.  The shift you seek is the slope of this plane, expressed as two scalar components $a$ and $b$.  Since phase wraps, the slopes are decomposed into integer and fractional parts, $a = a' + a''$ etc.  In eq. (14) you obtain the residual phase field by subtracting the phase due to the integer part $(a', b')$.  You need the actual $k$ values when you compute $(a'k_1 + b'k_2)$, not just the $k$ indices.  Computing the $k$ values is similar to making a frequency axis for a 1D Fourier spectrum analysis.

Comment: Hey I just saw your answer. I stopped looking at this paper for quite some time. Since now I have the response, would you mind we have a chat? I don't understand what you meant by the **actual k**. If I'm not wrong it's the frequencies. If so, it's very straight forward for 1D signal with sampling rate, but since this is an image without the sampling rate, would you mind explain how could I obtain it?

Comment: I managed to get the *k* values, however, when you said subtracting the phase due to the integer part *(a′,b′)*, how can I obtain that values? If according to the paper, its says by using the POC, By using POC, I successfully get the values for the **integer shift**, but **not the slopes** of the integer shift. The paper is quite confusing.